# Use angularjs ng-blur with a call to javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use AngularJs 1.3.4

```
$scope.change = function (id) {
    console.log("test onChange... " + id);
};
```

`<input ng-change="change({{question.id}})"` **is OK**

but `<input ng-blur="change({{question.id}})"` have a **syntaxe error**

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 9 of the expression [change({{question.id}})] starting at [{question.id}})].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.4/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=9&p3=change(%7B%7Bquestion.id%7D%7D)&p4=%7Bquestion.id%7D%7D)
    at http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using "{{var}}" in the call at all, angular automatically interpolates values in the scope. All you need to do is:

```
<input ng-blur="change(question.id)" />
```

My guess is ng-blur and ng-change handle them differently because it's against standard.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the time of parsing of the arguments.

`ngBlur` directive try to parse `{{question.id}}` at the compile time. This is an incorrect syntax for angular $parse.

`ngChange` parses `{{question.id}}` when event occurs and the value has been already interpolated, that is why you don't call `ng-change` function with `{{question.id}}`, at the place of the placeholder the exact value is